Can the verb 洗う be used interchangeably?
So, I’ve noticed that a lot of verbs are specific to certain actions and/on certain objects. Can 洗う be used for washing ANY object, animate or inanimate or otherwise? Can I use it to talk about washing my dog, hands, car, clothes, plates, etc?

As far as the most basic meaning goes, yes, 洗う can be used with dogs, hands, cars, clothes, plates, fruits, and many others.
Exceptions where 洗う won't work well include:

birds washing their feathers → 毛づくろいする
tears washing one's face → 涙で顔が濡れる
washing with a thin coat of paint → ペンキで薄く塗る

Conversely, 洗う has some unique usages including this.
But these are relatively minor differences, and you can safely start by thinking "wash" is 洗う in most cases. You can see this ALC entry for other possible translations of various minor usages of "wash".

Thank you so much!!
